# How to do a fallback img in v-img in Vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

In Vuetify I have a `v-img`, and I want to change the image to a fallback one if the main one fails.

```
<v-img :src="cPicture" contain v-on:error="onImgError"></v-img>


cPicture : function() {
            return this.failed_image ? "https://assets.dryicons.com/uploads/icon/svg/9872/ab3c0a16-6f14-4817-a30b-443273de911d.svg" : "http://myimg.jpg/";
        },


onImgError : function(event) {
            alert(1);
            this.failed_image = true;
            //this.$forceUpdate();
        },
```

the alert 1 happens. `Vuetify` also throws an error in the console. But the fallback image does not show.

How can I fix this?

The main image above has intentionally a bad link, but if I use a good link, it will be shown.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use `cPicture` as a computed property and `onImgError` as a method :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      failed_image: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    cPicture: function() {
      return this.failed_image ? "https://picsum.photos/500/300?image=4" : "https://pisum.photos/500/300?image=5";
    },



  },
  methods: {
    onImgError: function(event) {

      this.failed_image = true;

    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.3.7/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-layout>
      <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
        <v-card>
          <v-container grid-list-sm fluid>
            <v-img :src="cPicture" contain v-on:error="onImgError"></v-img>
          </v-container>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

check this [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rQepZp?editors=1011)

**EDIT**

I had provided an invalid image link for the desired image, in this case we will have an exception which will be shown in console :

> "[Vuetify] Image load failed

in this case we will load another image with a valid link

Comment: Verbose solution when dealing with lists of images, if it's your case try out the @Maurilio Atila solution.

Answer (score 4):

I do the same thing, but with less code.

```
<v-img tile :src="logo.url" v-on:error="logo.url='/logo.svg'" />
```

Answer (score 2):

This has been asked on [github](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/5876#issuecomment-942376257) and should be added in Vuetify 3

Here is my way of solving this in the meantime

I first create two data

```js
data(): {
 avatarLoadingFailed: false,
 fallbackAvatar: fallbackAvatar,
}
```

`fallbackAvatar` is the image file I want to display in case of loading failure

Then I create a computed to hold the avatar to be displayed

```js
computed: {
  avatar() {
    return this.avatarLoadingFailed
      ? this.fallbackAvatar
      : this.getUserAvatar;
  },
}
```

Finally in my `template` tag

```html
// @error="avatarLoadingFailed = true" works fine as well
<v-img :src="avatar" v-on:error="avatarLoadingFailed = true"/>
```

I have tried and tested this in VueJS with and without typescript

Answer (score 1):

I like what @maurilio-atila did. In my case image was coming from another server and I ended up doing this:

```
 <v-img :src="`${item.image ?`https://some/endpoint/${item.image}` : '/fallback.png'}`"/>
```

While it doesn't handle `v-on:error`, it avoids it.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality was added to Vuetify 3. You need to use the v-img error slot. In the following example, there are some typos in the first supplied source image, so the second source contained within the error slot will be used.

```
<v-img src="https://pisum.phots/500/300?imige=4">
  <template v-slot:error>
    <v-img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300?image=5"></v-img>
  </template>
</v-img>
```