# How to replace <img> src when the image URL is broken in Vue3?

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, vuejs3, src

I have a list of data table rows rendered in Vue3 with a v-for directive. In each row there is a  tag with a src URL to the image online. Whenever the image URL is broken (the image does not exist anymore), I would like the src URL to change to a default value.

With jQuery I could do the following:

```
        $('img').on("error", function() {
            $(this).attr('src', 'fallbackURL');
          });
```

How can I do something similar in Vue3? I am looking for the lightest possible solution as there could potentially be many rows and many broken image URLs. I would not mind keeping this jQuery solution but I do not know how to implement it in Vue.

Very thankful for any help!

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53215340/8172857

Comment: It's the same issue but with Vuetify which I do not use (v-img is not a native Vue directive) + the solution involves computed properties which I want to avoid, I was looking for the lightest possible solution. Thanks!

Comment: `v-img` inherits the `img` attributs, why do you want to avoid computed properties?

Comment: Why is this question closed? It's a different question, it doesn't matter that this question's answer can be found in another question.

Comment: add this to your img element: `@error="$event.target.src=fallbackImageUrl"`. If you're using `vite`, you have to import your fallback image url like so: `import fallbackImageUrl from '@/images/yourImage.png'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use Vue in this case, there is a native solution:

`<img src="..." onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='Default.jpg'" />`

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this using @error and put the function you want if the image is not found or broken then change the src to the default image.

Try it this way.

I use this as a default image -> https://i.ibb.co/5908vXL/Screenshot-from-2021-06-15-11-13-44.png

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <img src="test.png" @error="imageLoadOnError"/>
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
   imageLoadOnError(e) {
          e.target.src = "https://i.ibb.co/5908vXL/Screenshot-from-2021-06-15-11-13-44.png"
      }
  }
})
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is an elegant Vue solution, though I prefer the native solution in my case as it does not involve creating an extra function and data property

Comment: How can I do something similar in Vue3? you asked for doing it in vue3 so u can also use a skeleton image it will be more professional when the image is loading for example. I just answered what you really want . so check out the skeleton image in Vue and hard luck

Comment: You're right it answers the question the way I asked it. What I meant though was "in a Vue3 environment" but I reckon this might be the most relevant solution in many cases. Also I did not see the skeleton aspect, which could def be interesting in the future. Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome .. in Facebook or Twitter or Instagram when the image is loading there's like a gray background color is showing and it moves like waves this is what skeleton and good luck!