# How to provide a jpg fallback for a webp src in vuetify v-img?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I currently have:

```
<v-carousel
      class="carProfile-carousel"
      height="60vw"
      continuous
      cycle
      hide-delimiter-background
      show-arrows-on-hover
    >
      <v-carousel-item
        v-for="(item, i) in sortedImages"
        :key="i"
        itemprop="image"
      >
      <v-img :src="$config.imgsURL + item.image + imageSize + '.webp'" />
      </v-carousel-item>
    </v-carousel>
```

But i need a fallback for when the browser doesn't support webp. How could i implement it?

Example of fallback src:

```
:src="$config.imgsURL + item.image + imageSize + '.jpg'"
```

Comment: something similar was asked a little while ago. Does this solve your issue?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53215071/how-to-do-a-fallback-img-in-v-img-in-vuetify